# What are the origin and explanation for Dax's hands-behind-the-back mannerism?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, behind-the-scenes

Lt. Dax routinely walks and stands with her hands clasped behind her back.

Here's the clearest capture I could get, from "Blood Oath":

[image: A still from the aforementioned episode, showing Lieutenant Jadzia Dax walking away from the camera, with her hands clasped behind her back.]

The out-of-universe story is what really interests me. However, the in-universe explanation is relatively easy to find, so might as well include both in the answer.

Comment: Hey @ThePopMachine: if you're wondering about all the tag edits, they're to do with achieving consistency as per http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9184/ (you've just happened to have asked a lot of Trek questions, so naturally you'll be seeing these more than others).  Hope all is well.

Comment: @Praxis, thanks for the explanation.   I did get a bunch of onesie upvotes on random old questions,  I guess just because of the attention due to activity.

Comment: Whatever the reason, Ezri adopted the same gesture.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## To avoid smudging her makeup.

Your question has excellent timing, as actress Terry Farrell provided the out-of-universe explanation only a few months ago:

> The makeup itself provided yet another challenge. The spots being initially done in watercolour, she had to keep her neck very stiff to avoid smudging. Terry’s modelling training provided a solution: She began standing very straight with her hands behind her back. This quickly became her trademark stance: “Once I owned that, no one else could!”

(Source — [Terry Farrell interview / panel Toronto ComicCon 2015](https://web.archive.org/web/20161001195832/http://geekinked.com/?p=2464))

The in-universe explanation is that Jadzia inherited the behaviour from Lela, the Dax symbiont's first host, as revealed in *DS9* ["Facets"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facets_(Star_Trek:_Deep_Space_Nine)). As a politician, Lela clasped her hands behind her back to keep control of her gesturing during public addresses.

Comment: Oh.. (disappointed) and there I was, hoping it would be to maximize and showcase the breast mound! *"Sorry, the [breast mound](http://www.huffingtonpost.com.au/2012/04/11/jeri-ryan-body-of-proof-star-trek-voyager_n_1413141.html?ir=Australia)?"*

Comment: I'm sort of disappointed she doesn't claim it's a mannerism she invented to convey her long life and wisdom.   So much for the craft.

Comment: @ThePopMachine: Indeed. I had somehow hoped it was a slight hommage to [Spock](http://img13.deviantart.net/66f5/i/2013/217/0/8/spock_by_amandatolleson-d6gsfq4.png), with Jadzia being the first designated science officer in a Star Trek series since TOS that we saw.

Comment: @Praxis While you're updating this, the interview link is dead...